# PNPM installation does not update minor or patch versions even with caret (^)

Tags: reactjs, npm, semantic-versioning, pnpm

PNPM seems to install exactly the version specified in package.json and doesn't seem that to install the latest minor version.

For example, In my package.json i have this dependency
`"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.13.5"`

But while installing, pnpm gives this message
`@tanstack/react-query 4.13.5 (4.29.5 is available)`

So my question is, why doesn't pnpm install *4.29.5* like npm does with the caret?
And how do i achieve this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue on my windows machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to achieve this in pnpm, you must use `resolution-mode=highest` in your `.npmrc` file.
while it doesn't exactly say in the docs (linked below) what `highest` does, it's pretty clear from what the other options are: `time-based`, and `lowest-direct`

> When `resolution-mode` is set to `time-based`, dependencies will be
> resolved the following way:
>
> Direct dependencies will be resolved to their lowest versions. So if
> there is `foo@^1.1.0` in the dependencies, then `1.1.0` will be installed.
>
> Subdependencies will be resolved from versions that were published
> before the last direct dependency was published.
>
> When `resolution-mode` is set to `lowest-direct`, direct dependencies will
> be resolved to their lowest versions.

more info:
https://pnpm.io/npmrc#resolution-mode